# how to change the the margin value with a count down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, margin, countdowntimer

Would anyone be able to help me with this?

Here is what I have now 
http://jsfiddle.net/fergu0516/GAVDA/

```
        var leave = 200;
        if(leave > 0)
        {
            CounterTimer();
        }
        function CounterTimer() 
        {
        var minute = Math.floor(leave / 60);
        var second = Math.floor(leave) - (minute*60);            
        minute=minute<10 ? "0" + minute : minute; 
        second=second<10 ? "0" + second : second;

        var remain = minute + ":" + second;
        leave = leave-1 ;
        document.getElementById("clkTimer").innerHTML = remain;            


        if(leave >= 0)
          {
              setTimeout(CounterTimer,1000);
          }
        else
          {
            alert("Your cart is expired!")
            window.location = "#";                
          }
        }
    $(document).ready(function(){

// The relative URL of the submit.php script.
// You will probably have to change it.

// Caching the feedback object: 
var feedback = $('#feedback');

$('#feedback').click(function(){

    // We are storing the values of the animated
    // properties in a separate object:

    var anim    = {     
        mb : 207,           // Margin Bottom
        pt : 0          // Padding Top
    };

    var el = $(this).find('.arrow');

    if(el.hasClass('buttonright')){
        anim = {
            mb : 0,
            pt : 0
        };
    }

    // The first animation moves the form up or down, and the second one 
    // moves the "Feedback heading" so it fits in the minimized version

    feedback.stop().animate({marginRight: anim.mb});

    feedback.find('.section').stop().animate({paddingTop:anim.pt},function(){
        el.toggleClass('buttonright buttonleft');
    });
});

    });
```

I need to have the same effect as the sample: what happens now is that when I press the red box the timer shows by giving the (div id="feedback") a margin-right of 207px.

What I need here is this to happen automatically when the time hits 1:00. So when the timer hits 1:00 the window will show, by adding margin-right:207px to the object.

Thank you so much, anything would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/uWBUT/#fork)

do something like this:

```
    if(leave == 60){
        $('#feedback').trigger('click');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
if (leave == 60)
{
   $('#feedback').stop().animate({marginRight: 207});   
}
```

to the `CounterTimer()` function. Maybe after the `leave = leave - 1;` line.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add an `if` statement to find out `if(leave == 60)`, and if so you can then animate the element to its "visible" `margin-right` value.

Comment: yes, I know that I need that if statement, I just don't know how to put it in code. My code is here:  http://jsfiddle.net/fergu0516/GAVDA/

Comment: put it somewhere in the CounterTimer() function.